# How to remove the '%20' from a url in Python?

Tags: python, string, url, formatting

I'm trying to remove with Python (Not C#, PHP or others) the %20 symbol from a url after having transformed it into a string. However the symbol keeps staying unchanged no matter what formatting I tried.

here is the code I tried:

```
url = 'https://www.amazon.com/s?k=hbb%20magic%20dress' # Type string

title_text_data_file = url.split('=')[1]
if '%20'in title_text_data_file:
    title_text_data_file = title_text_data_file.replace('%20+', '')
    keyword = title_text_data_file.replace('+', ' ')
    title_text_data_file = title_text_data_file + ".txt"
    print('Keyword:',keyword,'- File title:',title_text_data_file,'- URL:',url)
```

Here is what I get:

```
Keyword: hbb%20magic%20dress - File title: hbb%20magic%20dress.txt - URL: https://www.amazon.com/s?k=hbb%20magic%20dress
```

Here is what I would like to get:

```
Keyword: hbb magic dress - File title: hbb+magic+dress.txt - URL: https://www.amazon.com/s?k=hbb%20magic%20dress
```

Comment: `replace('%20+', '')` will replace `'%20+'` with empty string. Isn't just `'%20'` you need to replace?

Comment: There's a lot more than `%20` that you need to deal with.  See the above link for info on the Python lib that does this, which is `urllib.parse.unquote`.

Comment: Hi @TomKarzes, I'm trying to modify the string without importing additional libraries or make the code heavier.

Comment: @AmatoIlCiabattaro I would suggest that writing your own code to do this is far "heavier" than importing something that truly solves the problem, rather than handling just 5% of the cases you may encounter.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

> str.replace(old, new[, max])

you can not replace unexist string.

```py
title_text_data_file = url.split('=')[1]
if '%20'in title_text_data_file:
    key = '%20'
    title_text_data_file = title_text_data_file.replace(key, '+')
    keyword = title_text_data_file.replace('+', ' ')
    title_text_data_file = title_text_data_file + ".txt"
    print('Keyword:',keyword,'- File title:',title_text_data_file,'- URL:',url)
```

```
Keyword: hbb magic dress - File title: hbb+magic+dress.txt - URL: https://www.amazon.com/s?k=hbb%20magic%20dress
```

Answer (score 6):

Python Urllib.parse module can be used to convert the encoded url.

Example

```
import urllib.parse
url = 'https://www.amazon.com/s?k=hbb%20magic%20dress' # Type string
urllib.parse.unquote(url) # Returns 'https://www.amazon.com/s?k=hbb magic dress'
urllib.parse.unquote(url).replace(" ","") # Returns 'https://www.amazon.com/s?k=hbbmagicdress'
```

Answer (score 5):

Actually, it is better to use libraries designed to deal with urls, as that will handle any urlencoded characters, not just spaces (`%20`). The standard library provides the [`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) module.

In your case you want to use

```
import urllib.parse
url = 'https://www.amazon.com/s?k=hbb%20magic%20dress'
# This extracts the query part from the url
query = urllib.parse.urlparse(url).query
# This gets the first k parameter, decoding any urlencoded character, not only spaces(%20)
keyword = urllib.parse.parse_qs(query)['k'][0]
```